# iCloud exception the operation couldn't be completed no such file or directory, iOS8

Tags: exception, core-data, ios8, icloud

Core data over iOS/ works fine, but while getting update or writing to the database in iOS 8, I get

2014-09-19 01:16:31.819 xxxxxx[369:57150] __45-[PFUbiquityFilePresenter processPendingURLs]_block_invoke(439): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Librarian returned a serious error for starting downloads Error Domain=BRCloudDocsErrorDomain Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed.

(BRCloudDocsErrorDomain error 5 - No document at URL)" UserInfo=0x175a85c0 {NSDescription=No document at URL, NSUnderlyingError=0x175aefb0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory",

NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/xxxxx/CoreData/ATracker/mobile~268B3375-7A17-4FFA-89DE-AE1BF8DDB134/xxxxx/OJ~PXmuzk0E_yZN9NTVWA20~k_qcPzNgyW_uT_mz098=/8929F33C-BB6A-48B6-B16C-BF612D04D947.1.cdt} with userInfo {

```
NSDescription = "No document at URL";
NSFilePath = "/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/xxxxx~xxxx~xxxxx/CoreData/xxxxx/mobile~268B3375-7A17-4FFA-89DE-AE1BF8DDB134/xxxxx/OJ~PXmuzk0E_yZN9NTVWA20~k_qcPzNgyW_uT_mz098=/8929F33C-BB6A-48B6-B16C-BF612D04D947.1.cdt";
NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. No such file or directory\" UserInfo=0x175c2d50 {NSDescription=No such file or directory}";
```

} for these urls: (

```
"file:///var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/xxxxx~xxxx~xxxxx/CoreData/xxxxx/mobile~268B3375-7A17-4FFA-89DE-AE1BF8DDB134/xxxxx/OJ~PXmuzk0E_yZN9NTVWA20~k_qcPzNgyW_uT_mz098=/8929F33C-BB6A-48B6-B16C-BF612D04D947.1.cdt"
```

)

Answer (score 5):

I had similar problem, not with iCloud, but with mainBundle. It could be that you are saving URL or filePath of your documents and then trying to read them by that URL/ filePath. However in iOS8 location of mainBundle is different (xxxxx~xxxx~xxxxx part of URL) each time you run your app. So you should save only file name and get the URL/ filePath for that on the fly each time. I'm not sure if this applies to iCloud Documents as well, but I hope this helps or leads you to the right direction.

Comment: Thanks! I reread my code, I used "[[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]] URLByAppendingPathComponent:storeFilename]" , the directory is [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES) lastObject], filename is just the name of the file. So you mentioned it create a different one sometimes, which may cause conflict.

Comment: It does not work. the App creating a new folder in CoreDataUbiquitySupport in new app version, even there is an folder existing already. It does not crash the app, but all user data are lost after the upgrade (although not happening for all users). the folder it created again is the mobile-xxxxx ones, the coredata folder after it is still using the same ID.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I have contacted Apple on this issue. The feedback is. First, there is some "feature" in XCode to provide different folder name in debug depends on the version and the machine ID. Second, it might be a potential bug in Apple's code and the Apple developer support asked me to create a ticket so they can analyse and fix the bug in future release. Result, I fully disabled the iCloud sync feature from my app. I do get some angry and negative feedback from users, but at least there is no data loss from now on.

Comment: I am generating the url each time the app runs and only storing the FileName. i still get this error in core data with iCloud. it is causing a lot of inconsistency and data loss in my app. its frustrating. i plan to disable icloud too.

Comment: one thing i have noticed is that even with this error icloud sets up fine eventually.